# How to change Android 2.1 themes?

Tags: themes

I just bought Xperia x10 and upgraded it to Android 2.1 but I am struggling with themes. I have downloaded couple of them from the market but I do not know how to install them. How do I change themes for Android 2.1?

Comment: Can you post a link to which themes you've downloaded. Also, are you using the stock launcher or some other customised one like ADW or Launcher Pro?

Comment: here are couple of them: http://www.androidzoom.com/android_themes/themes/adw-ubuntu-theme_jwln.html  and http://www.androidzoom.com/android_themes/themes/adwtheme-one_irwm.html   and I have not idea what the stock launcher is?

Comment: Your links are for an ADW theme - you need to install ADW Launcher to use this theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use those themes, you'll need to use the alternative launcher ADW.

As it says at the top of the description:

> `*Must have adw.launcher 1.3.1+ to use*`

http://www.appbrain.com/app/adw-launcher/org.adw.launcher